# Show BarChar In JTable Column In Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, bar-chart, renderer

I have JTable in that I need to Show Chart but i have tired several Code but not able to achieve waht i wanted to make. here what i have tried so far

http://www.jroller.com/Thierry/entry/swing_barchart_rendering_in_a

and i want to achieve according to this image

[image]

but how ever i dont get any Render-er for same. 
Please Any suggestion will be welcomed.

[image: Example]

Comment: Don't think `JTable` is going to be able to do that...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i dont have single idea. :( because all values coming from webservices that i need to show. but its accordingly what i got form service. but is it possible to do by table? i dont know may be NO.

Comment: Because you seem to be able to have values to fall midstream to a column, then I would say it would be headache to manage.  Each row should be it's own component, with some kind of controller that tells these rows what the row information and it's offsets (so I you could ask for the x pixel position for a given time period)

Comment: @MadProgrammer ya it would be complex. to manage. but any other good way that i can achieve this?

Comment: @MadProgrammer painting ? i mean is that will implement by Jtable?

Comment: Nope, brand new component

Comment: @MadProgrammer then please tell me how to make it. is it manual component that we will make?

Comment: @MadProgrammer and ya bro there is not need to take 8,9,10.. that much header if i can just add one column instead of that and i can show that component that will be enough.

Comment: The problem is a single column might need to present multiple entries

Comment: @MadProgrammer can i share one idea? :)

Comment: Sure, knock yourself out

Comment: @MadProgrammer brother if i put that labels in Jtable cells i mean from 8 to 24 will have label and if i color it. will it work and is it possible i mean that 8 to 24 hours is something like working hours of employee and between it have other colors of Break hours. so if i do that way will it work or is it possible to add two labels bcoz that way might be it possible..

Comment: It all "depends" how would you represent a period that doesn't "fit"

Comment: @MadProgrammer ya that is even correct. :( but how can i make it perfact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's an idea...

[image: Layout]

Instead of using a `JTable`, you could create a layout manager which would calculate the offsets and allow for elements to overlap "columns"

**Prototype example - !! DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION !!**

[image]

This is an EXAMPLE only and should be used to LEARN from, do not try using this in production, there is a lot that needs to improved, such as a proper event notification API

This example makes use of the JIDE Common Layer API (the `JideScrollPane` in particular), you can get a copy from [here](https://github.com/jidesoft/jide-oss)

```
import com.jidesoft.swing.JideScrollPane;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager2;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;

public class WorkSheetReport {

    public static final Color WORKING_HOURS_COLOR = new Color(93, 89, 88);
    public static final Color LUNCH_HOURS_COLOR = new Color(215, 142, 27);
    public static final Color OTHER_HOURS_COLOR = new Color(30, 141, 213);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WorkSheetReport();
    }

    public WorkSheetReport() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTimeSheetReport report = new DefaultTimeSheetReport();
                report.add(createTimeSheet(
                                "NWD/Full"));
                report.add(createTimeSheet(
                                "Present",
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 10, 12.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.LUNCH, 12.5, 13.25),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 13.25, 18),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.OTHER, 18, 18.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 18.5, 20.5)));
                report.add(createTimeSheet(
                                "0.5UUPL",
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 10, 12.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.LUNCH, 12.5, 17.75),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.OTHER, 17.75, 18),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 18, 20)));
                report.add(createTimeSheet(
                                "Present",
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 11, 13),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.LUNCH, 13, 13.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 13.5, 17.75),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.OTHER, 17.75, 18),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 18, 20.5)));
                report.add(createTimeSheet(
                                "Present",
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 10, 12.75),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.LUNCH, 12.75, 13.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 13.5, 17.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.OTHER, 17.5, 17.75),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 17.75, 20.5)));
                report.add(createTimeSheet(
                                "Present",
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 9.75, 12),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.LUNCH, 12, 12.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 12.5, 17.25),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.OTHER, 17.25, 17.75),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 17.75, 20)));
                report.add(createTimeSheet(
                                "Present",
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 10, 11.75),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.LUNCH, 11.75, 12.25),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 12.25, 17.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.OTHER, 17.5, 18),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 18, 20.25)));
                report.add(createTimeSheet(
                                "NWD/Full"));
                report.add(createTimeSheet(
                                "Present",
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 10, 12.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.LUNCH, 12.5, 13.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 13.5, 18),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.OTHER, 18, 18.5),
                                new DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType.WORK, 18.5, 20.5)));

                TimeSheetReportPane pane = new TimeSheetReportPane(report);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JideScrollPane sp = new JideScrollPane(pane);
                sp.setColumnHeadersHeightUnified(true);
                frame.add(sp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    protected TimeSheet createTimeSheet(String name, TimeEntry... entries) {
        DefaultTimeSheet ts = new DefaultTimeSheet(name);
        for (TimeEntry entry : entries) {
            ts.add(entry);
        }
        return ts;
    }

    protected static String format(double time) {
        time *= 60 * 60; // to seconds
        int hours = (int) Math.floor(time / (60 * 60));
        double remainder = time % (60 * 60);
        int mins = (int) Math.floor(remainder / 60);
        int secs = (int) Math.floor(time % 60);
        return hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
    }

    public class TimeSheetReportPane extends JPanel {

        private TimeSheetReport report;

        private int columnWidth;
        private int rowHeight;

        public TimeSheetReportPane(TimeSheetReport report) {
            this.report = report;
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));
            columnWidth = fm.stringWidth("0000");
            rowHeight = fm.getHeight() + 8;

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 1, 0);

            int count = 0;
            for (TimeSheet ts : report) {

                Color color = getColorForSheet(count);
                TimeSheetPane pane = new TimeSheetPane(this, ts);
                pane.setBackground(color);
                add(pane, gbc);
                count++;

            }

            gbc.weighty = 1;
            JPanel fill = new JPanel();
            fill.setOpaque(false);
            add(fill, gbc);

        }

        public Color getColorForSheet(int index) {
            Color endColor = Color.GRAY;
            Color startColor = Color.DARK_GRAY;
            double progress = (double) index / (double) getReport().size();
            return blend(startColor, endColor, progress);
        }

        public TimeSheetReport getReport() {
            return report;
        }

        public int getRowHeight() {
            return rowHeight;
        }

        public int getColumnWidth() {
            return columnWidth;
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            configureEnclosingScrollPane();
        }

        protected void configureEnclosingScrollPane() {
            Container parent = getParent();
            if (parent instanceof JViewport) {
                JViewport viewport = (JViewport) parent;
                parent = viewport.getParent();
                if (parent instanceof JideScrollPane) {
                    JideScrollPane sp = (JideScrollPane) parent;
                    sp.setRowFooterView(new RowFooter(this));
                }
                if (parent instanceof JScrollPane) {
                    JScrollPane sp = (JScrollPane) parent;
                    JLabel leftHeader = new JLabel("Status");
                    leftHeader.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    leftHeader.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    leftHeader.setOpaque(true);
                    leftHeader.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    leftHeader.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
                    leftHeader.setBorder(new EdgeBorder(EdgeBorder.Edge.RIGHT, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK));
                    sp.setCorner(ScrollPaneConstants.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER, leftHeader);

                    JLabel rightHeader = new JLabel("Working Hr");
                    rightHeader.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    rightHeader.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    rightHeader.setOpaque(true);
                    rightHeader.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    rightHeader.setBorder(new EdgeBorder(EdgeBorder.Edge.LEFT, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK));
                    sp.setCorner(ScrollPaneConstants.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER, rightHeader);

                    sp.setRowHeaderView(new RowHeader(this));
                    sp.setColumnHeaderView(new ColumnHeader(this));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class ColumnHeader extends JPanel {

        private TimeSheetReportPane reportPane;

        public ColumnHeader(TimeSheetReportPane tsrp) {
            reportPane = tsrp;
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
            gbc.ipady = 8;
            Border border = new MatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.GRAY);

            for (int hour = 8; hour < 25; hour++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(Integer.toString(hour)) {

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize();
                        dim.width = reportPane.getColumnWidth();
                        return dim;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                        return getPreferredSize();
                    }

                };
                label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                label.setBorder(border);
                add(label, gbc);
            }
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            JPanel fill = new JPanel();
            fill.setOpaque(false);
            add(fill, gbc);

        }

    }

    public class RowHeader extends JPanel {

        private TimeSheetReportPane reportPane;

        public RowHeader(TimeSheetReportPane tsrp) {
            reportPane = tsrp;
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            TimeSheetReport tsr = reportPane.getReport();

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.ipadx = 16;
            gbc.ipady = 2;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 1, 0);

            int index = 0;
            for (TimeSheet ts : tsr) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel(ts.getName()) {

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize();
                        dim.height = reportPane.getRowHeight();
                        return dim;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                        return getPreferredSize();
                    }

                };
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                label.setBackground(reportPane.getColorForSheet(index));
                label.setOpaque(true);
                add(label, gbc);
                index++;
            }
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            JPanel fill = new JPanel();
            fill.setOpaque(false);
            add(fill, gbc);

        }

    }

    public class RowFooter extends JPanel {

        private TimeSheetReportPane reportPane;

        public RowFooter(TimeSheetReportPane tsrp) {
            reportPane = tsrp;
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            TimeSheetReport tsr = reportPane.getReport();

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.ipadx = 36;
            gbc.ipady = 2;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 1, 0);

            int index = 0;
            for (TimeSheet ts : tsr) {
                double time = ts.getWorkingHours();
                String workHrs = "";
                if (time > 0) {
                    workHrs = format(time);
                }
                JLabel label = new JLabel(workHrs) {

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize();
                        dim.height = reportPane.getRowHeight();
                        return dim;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                        return getPreferredSize();
                    }

                };
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                label.setBackground(reportPane.getColorForSheet(index));
                label.setOpaque(true);
                add(label, gbc);
                index++;
            }
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            JPanel fill = new JPanel();
            fill.setOpaque(false);
            add(fill, gbc);

        }

    }

    public static class EdgeBorder implements Border {

        public enum Edge {

            LEFT,
            RIGHT
        }

        private Edge edge;
        private Color startColor;
        private Color endColor;

        public EdgeBorder(Edge edge, Color startColor, Color endColor) {
            this.edge = edge;
            this.startColor = startColor;
            this.endColor = endColor;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {

            int xPos = x;
            switch (edge) {
                case RIGHT:
                    xPos = x + (width - 1);
            }

            LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                            new Point(x, 0),
                            new Point(x, height),
                            new float[]{0, 1},
                            new Color[]{startColor, endColor});

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setPaint(lgp);
            g2d.drawLine(xPos, y, xPos, y + height);
        }

        @Override
        public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
            int left = edge == Edge.LEFT ? 1 : 0;
            int right = edge == Edge.RIGHT ? 1 : 0;
            return new Insets(0, left, 0, right);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
            return false;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Blend two colors.
     *
     * @param color1 First color to blend.
     * @param color2 Second color to blend.
     * @param ratio Blend ratio. 0.5 will give even blend, 1.0 will return color1,
     * 0.0 will return color2 and so on.
     * @return Blended color.
     */
    public static Color blend(Color color1, Color color2, double ratio) {
        float r = (float) ratio;
        float ir = (float) 1.0 - r;

        float rgb1[] = new float[3];
        float rgb2[] = new float[3];

        color1.getColorComponents(rgb1);
        color2.getColorComponents(rgb2);

        float red = rgb1[0] * r + rgb2[0] * ir;
        float green = rgb1[1] * r + rgb2[1] * ir;
        float blue = rgb1[2] * r + rgb2[2] * ir;

        if (red < 0) {
            red = 0;
        } else if (red > 255) {
            red = 255;
        }
        if (green < 0) {
            green = 0;
        } else if (green > 255) {
            green = 255;
        }
        if (blue < 0) {
            blue = 0;
        } else if (blue > 255) {
            blue = 255;
        }

        Color color = null;
        try {

            color = new Color(red, green, blue);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        return color;
    }

    public class TimeSheetPane extends JPanel {

        private final JPanel timeEntriesPane;

        public TimeSheetPane(TimeSheetReportPane reportPane, TimeSheet ts) {

            timeEntriesPane = new JPanel(new TimeSheetLayoutManager(reportPane.getColumnWidth(), reportPane.getRowHeight()));
            timeEntriesPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(1, 0, 1, 0));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(timeEntriesPane);

            for (TimeEntry te : ts) {
                JLabel label = createLabel(te.getType().getColor());
                String startTime = format(te.getStartTime());
                String duration = format(te.getDuration());
                label.setToolTipText("<html>StartTime: " + startTime + "<br>Duration: " + duration);
                timeEntriesPane.add(label, te);
            }

        }

        protected JLabel createLabel(Color color) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBackground(color);
            return label;
        }

    }

    public class TimeSheetLayoutManager implements LayoutManager2 {

        private Map<Component, TimeEntry> mapConstraints;
        private int colWidth;
        private int rowHeight;

        public TimeSheetLayoutManager(int colWidth, int rowHeight) {
            mapConstraints = new HashMap<>(25);
            this.colWidth = colWidth;
            this.rowHeight = rowHeight;
        }

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {
            if (constraints instanceof TimeEntry) {
                mapConstraints.put(comp, (TimeEntry) constraints);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                constraints == null ? "Null is not a valid constraint"
                                : constraints.getClass().getName() + " is not a valid TimeEntry constraint"
                );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension maximumLayoutSize(Container target) {
            return preferredLayoutSize(target);
        }

        @Override
        public float getLayoutAlignmentX(Container target) {
            return 0.5f;
        }

        @Override
        public float getLayoutAlignmentY(Container target) {
            return 0.5f;
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidateLayout(Container target) {
        }

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
            mapConstraints.remove(comp);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return new Dimension(colWidth * (24 - 8), rowHeight);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            return preferredLayoutSize(parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            Insets insets = parent.getInsets();
            int width = parent.getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
            int height = rowHeight;

            int hourWidth = colWidth;
            int offset = 8;

            for (Component comp : mapConstraints.keySet()) {
                TimeEntry te = mapConstraints.get(comp);
                double startTime = te.getStartTime();
                double duration = te.getDuration();

                startTime -= offset;

                int x = (int) Math.round(startTime * hourWidth);
                int unitWidth = (int) Math.round(duration * hourWidth);
                comp.setLocation(x, insets.top);
                comp.setSize(unitWidth, height);
            }
        }

    }

    public enum WorkType {

        WORK(WORKING_HOURS_COLOR),
        LUNCH(LUNCH_HOURS_COLOR),
        OTHER(OTHER_HOURS_COLOR);

        private Color color;

        private WorkType(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

    }

    public interface TimeEntry {

        public WorkType getType();

        public double getStartTime();

        public double getDuration();
    }

    public interface TimeSheet extends Iterable<TimeEntry> {

        public String getName();

        public int size();

        public TimeEntry get(int index);

        public double getWorkingHours();

    }

    public interface TimeSheetReport extends Iterable<TimeSheet> {

        public int size();

        public TimeSheet get(int index);

    }

    public class DefaultTimeEntry implements TimeEntry {

        private final double startTime;
        private final double endTime;
        private final WorkType workType;

        public DefaultTimeEntry(WorkType type, double startTime, double endTime) {
            this.startTime = startTime;
            this.endTime = endTime;
            this.workType = type;
        }

        @Override
        public double getStartTime() {
            return startTime;
        }

        public double getEndTime() {
            return endTime;
        }

        @Override
        public double getDuration() {
            return endTime - startTime;
        }

        @Override
        public WorkType getType() {
            return workType;
        }

    }

    public class DefaultTimeSheet implements TimeSheet {

        private final List<TimeEntry> timeEntries;
        private final String name;

        public DefaultTimeSheet(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            timeEntries = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        public TimeSheet add(TimeEntry te) {
            timeEntries.add(te);
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<TimeEntry> iterator() {
            return timeEntries.iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return timeEntries.size();
        }

        @Override
        public TimeEntry get(int index) {
            return timeEntries.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public double getWorkingHours() {
            double time = 0;
            for (TimeEntry te : this) {
                switch (te.getType()) {
                    case WORK:
                        time += te.getDuration();
                        break;
                }
            }
            return time;
        }

    }

    public class DefaultTimeSheetReport implements TimeSheetReport {

        private final List<TimeSheet> timeSheets;

        public DefaultTimeSheetReport() {
            timeSheets = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        public DefaultTimeSheetReport add(TimeSheet ts) {
            timeSheets.add(ts);
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return timeSheets.size();
        }

        @Override
        public TimeSheet get(int index) {
            return timeSheets.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<TimeSheet> iterator() {
            return timeSheets.iterator();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would try 3 columns table. For the middle column I would use a custom renderer - a JPanel with JLabels on it. The labels could have different columns and sizes.

The TableModel should keep datasource for the bars and preparing renderer component means reading the cell value, extracting barchar data from the cell and setting colors/sizes for the JLabels in the JPanel (renderer component)

Comment: U have any Reference to tell me about this??

Comment: I need example Reference if u can give.

Comment: I don't have such an example. Just implement the method getTableCellRendererComponent() to return a JPanel with JLabels. The JPanel could have BoxLayout. All you need is to define the JLabels' colors and call setPreferredSize() for each JLabel according to the chart values

Comment: but how that label can extend into the columns? means if i have more area then how it will colored more area like 8 to 9 or 8 to 11?

Comment: I guess that's the problem, a single might need to represent two or more time slots, where a individual cell would, techniqually contain a single value. You could fundge it, but hats so lot of work at converting the time units to a table model, and we don't know if the time scale can be zoomed out not

Comment: @MadProgrammer m totally agree with u bro.