# Java how to display line number on the right side of text components

Tags: java, jtextarea, line-numbers, rights

I want to display line numbers in a text component. I found this link
https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/text-component-line-number/
And it worked. But I want to display line number on the right side of textarea. How can I do it. Thank!

Comment: You would have to modify it, to make that optional.  The paintComponent method is hardcoded to assume that the numbers are on the left (and as written, it does not appear to provide set/get methods for the data to allow extending without modifying the existing code).

Comment: JScrollPane doesn't support this by itself. You will have to uses something like JideScrollPane

Comment: For a, convoluted, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401969/show-barchar-in-jtable-column-in-java/24407816#24407816)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextLineNumber` is a Swing component. How do you display multiple components in a scroll pane? You add the components to a panel and then add the panel to the viewport of the scroll pane. One way might be to use a panel with a BorderLayout:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
TextLineNumber lineNumber = new TextLineNumber(textArea, 3);
panel.add(lineNumber, BorderLayout.EAST);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panel );
```

Or you could use the existing code and change the orientation of the scroll pane:

```
scrollPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

The line number will be on the right, but the scrollbar will now be on the left.

Comment: Thank you vey much! scrollPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); It worked for me! :). It extratly that i want.