# customized java swing Jtree layout(checkbox)

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtree, jcheckbox

I want to created tree on java swing, i use JTree component,the thing I want to do is created with checkbox,i seen many ways to do that,but i want let checkboxes beside tree,not in the tree.Is there anybody can help me? The picture below is the conception.

[image: layout i want to do]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add checkbox to JTree node to manage multiselection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870908/how-to-add-checkbox-to-jtree-node-to-manage-multiselection)

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375773/how-do-you-make-components-of-jpanel-as-a-node-in-jtree-usable/31376208#31376208)?

Comment: no,i want is all checkbox in same vertical line beside tree

Comment: Then I'd start by taking a look at [`JScrollPane#setRowHeader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setRowHeader(javax.swing.JViewport)) (for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248084/how-to-display-row-header-on-jtable-instead-of-column-header/26248635#26248635), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010090/moving-the-visible-area-of-a-jscrollpane-to-a-specific-position/34011257#34011257), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401969/show-barchar-in-jtable-column-in-java/24407816#24407816))

Comment: Or be preapred to get very, very farmiluar with the `JTree` look and feel delegates