# What GUI component should I use?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on my homework assignment and I have to achieve the following layout. Can anyone guide me as to how to achieve the right side of the view? I have already coded the left part, it's just the right side that I don't know what to use?

### Calendar GUI

[image]

Should I just use `paintComponent` or a `JTable`?

Comment: The question you need to ask, do appointments need to expand across multiple rows?  If they do, then I'd discourage the use of `JTable`

Comment: Yes, the way it is right now is time cell spans two rows and the corresponding is textfield of 2 rows.

Comment: You could have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401969/show-barchar-in-jtable-column-in-java/24407816#24407816) which basically is a horizontal fill, rather then a vertical fill, but the point is, with a well designed layout manager, you can do some surprisingly complex things

Comment: you can use Javafx, it so easy to implements

Comment: check this link https://github.com/dlemmermann/CalendarFX

Comment: It has to be done in Swing only, haven't been taught JavaFX yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JTable doesn't seems to suit your needs. You can consider using an array of [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) which will be added into a [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).

[image]

In this case, you can make use of the existing behaviours from these JComponents, such as setting them as editable/non-editable. Auto scrolling for JTextArea. JTextArea also allows displaying of multiple lines of records.

> Should I just use paintComponent

I supposed you meant by custom painting. Using custom painting will give you alot of freedom to do your own customizations, however if the current JComponents are able to fulfill you needs, then I think you shouldn't try to reinvent the wheel, especially when you need to deal with printing text. Aligning the text properly in custom painting could cost you alot more time than learning how to use various existing JComponents.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about JTA. What do you think should I use for the timings? Like, is it using GridBagLayout? Somehow, I can't think of any way to the time label to span two rows.

Comment: Yeah that would probably be the best idea. And then I can make the main panel scrollable