# How To Freeze My Last Column in Java Swing JTable

Tags: java, swing

- I used code from
  https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/
- It's Working Fine But I Need To Fix My Last Column
- I Changed scrollPane.setCorner property But No Use

Comment: By default `JScrollPane` doesn't have a row footer, which would allow you to do this, you need to either implement the functionality yourself or find a implementation which does - [maybe something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401969/show-barchar-in-jtable-column-in-java/24407816#24407816)